# calculate the number of a word in a txt file at linux terminal

Tags: linux

I want to calculate how many times a word in my txt file has passed.

Then,
[if count (word1) - count (word2)> 0 ...]
I want to do something like that.

When I entered something like that, I got the count.

input:

```
grep -ow WORD1 FileName | wc -l
```

output:

```
5
```

But when I assigned it to a variable, I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to assign a command's output to a variable, use command substitution:

```
count="$(grep -ow WORD1 FileName | wc -l)"
```

Comment: Thanks!! I defined it as, count="$(grep -ow WORD1 FileName | wc -l)". Without the quotes gave the result I wanted!